# KindOfMagic (INotifyPropertyChange Attributes) not working with Silverlight 5 beta?

Tags: silverlight, mono.cecil, silverlight-5.0

http://kindofmagic.codeplex.com/ is a cool project to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface using just Attributes instead of writing verbose property-setters.
As far as I understand it is a MS build task that manipulates the IL using Mono.Cecil.

However - it seems that it is not working with Silverlight 5 beta projects. 
At least not on my machine. Can anybody confirm this?

And does anybody know the reason, why it works with Silverlight 4 but breaks with Version 5? Mono.Cecil?

(Unfortunately I didn't get an answer on the Codeplex project site.)

cheers,
Thomas

Comment: What doesn´t work? Do you get any errors?

Comment: No errors. It just doesn't compile. see my comment below.

Comment: I think you should inform the author of KindOfMagic about this problem and the silverlight team (www.silverlight.net)

Comment: I already asked the author, but he doesn't want to install the Silverlight 5 Tools *beta* at this time. But you're right, I should try to contact someone from the SL team. Thanks for your input!

Comment: posted same question at http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/229868/559907.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer - but a great solution.
I found another project http://github.com/SimonCropp/NotifyPropertyWeaver with the same approach, that works well under Silverlight 5 (beta). Besides that, NotifyPropertyWeaver has more functionality than KindOfMagic.

Answer (score 0):

What's not working about it?  There is no reason off the top of my head why it would not work.

Comment: in a Silverlight 5 project, the build fails. Unfortunately without any error or any message.  The output window says:  ------ Build started: Project: MagicTest, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------  
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========  
So there is no compilation, no manifest generation, no xap packaging, ... nothing.  When I deactivate Kind-of-Magic, it compiles without problems, but of course without the magic call to RaisePropertyChange().